# Javascript Regex Character Exclusion w/ Match

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to validate a text input. I can't figure out how to exclude some special characters from being disallowed. I'm using /[\W ]\g to invalidate inputs that contain anything but A-Za-z0-9_ using regex.prototype.match. However, I'd like to exclude: (, ), [, ], and -. How would that be possible?

EDIT: I worded my question poorly. To clarify, I would like to exclude everything but the mentioned special characters and the /w regex.

Comment: Your query is not clear. `\w` only search for word characters in a string, so anyways all special characters are already excluded.

Comment: Please provide a code sample with test cases.

Comment: You can use a negated class for this and you need to escape the special character, something like `[^\(\[\)\]]`.

Comment: @Titus `[^([)\]]` is shorter

Comment: @Titus  thanks, that works

Comment: @ctwheels yes, that is true but the concept is easier to understand when all of them are escaped.

Comment: @Titus I agree it may be easier to read. This is actually even shorter than what I originally presented and doesn't require any character escaping: `[^]([)]`

Comment: `[^]([)]` doesn't seem to work in JavaScript, I've tested in on Chrome, it may work in other environments or other programming languages.

Comment: @Titus, PCRE I believe doesn't care, JavaScript is a little more sensitive, so my previous comment won't work for JavaScript. Thanks for evaluating it!

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/9198c8jz/, is that what you need?